# jQuery ImageFlow linking text to scroll bar

Tags: jquery, imageflow

Extremely new to jQuery, but discovered this amazing image gallery scrolling thingy, and it is working very nicely. BUT, I am stuck. I've got 5 pictures in my ImageFlow. Under the Image flow box, I've got the names of the 5 pictures. I want the scroll bar to move to the correct image, when clicking on the image name. Does this make sense?
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ImageFlow has a glideTo function.

You could try calling it on your links

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.imageflow-link').click( function() {
        var imageId = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#imageFlow').glideTo(imageId);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Abd a link like

```
<a class="imageflow-link" href="4">Test link</a>
```

Comment: This in my link code `<a class="photo02" href="4">PHOTO TWO</a>`

Comment: And this is my script code:
`<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".photo02").click( function() {
        var imageId = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#myImageFlow").glideTo(imageId);

        return false;
    });
});

    
</script>`